# Is it possible to install the OS over the network?

Tags: system-installation

I've got a chromebook I want to install elementary os on to dual boot.  But my memory sticks all are the normal USB form factors, and the machine only has the tiny USB ports (USB-C).  And there's no DVD drive on it.

The only thing I can think of is to install over the network, but I can't seem to find any documentation about that.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If your chromebook supports PXE booting, then it's possible. Usually there is a "network" or "PXE" boot option, which may need to be enabled in the BIOS. It would require another machine to be configured so that it can serve the install media over the network to your chromebook.

Check out [Setting up a server for PXE network booting](https://debian-administration.org/article/478/Setting_up_a_server_for_PXE_network_booting) for some instructions on setting up linux (Debian) to handle this.

Also, if you're not familiar with PXE booting in general, you can check out the article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment).